# Conditionally change columns in csv based on value of another column

Tags: python

Starting with this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv') 
df['Data'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Data'], format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')
df.set_index('Data' , inplace=True)
```

The dataframe is something like this:

```
Data                  a      b      c
2017-04-25 15:00:00   2      1      25
2017-04-25 16:00:00   4      7      nan
2017-04-25 17:00:00   4      6      nan
2017-04-25 18:00:00   5      9      34
```

The objective is to substitute all values in a and b columns with np.nan if np.nan is in c column. Desired output:

```
Data                  a      b      c
2017-04-25 15:00:00   2      1      25
2017-04-25 16:00:00   nan    nan    nan
2017-04-25 17:00:00   nan    nan    nan
2017-04-25 18:00:00   5      9      34
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but is not very elegant. Hopefully someone else comes by with a better solution.

```
df['a'] = df.loc[~df['c'].isnull()]['a']
df['b'] = df.loc[~df['c'].isnull()]['b']
```

Or in one line:

```
df[['a','b']] = df.loc[~df['c'].isnull()][['a','b']]
```